# using log4net for general purposes

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a c# .Net 3.5 application which reads multiple xml  files and i want to build in a performance logging facility. I have looked at log4net for c# and it seems to do everything when it comes to logging exceptions.

What I want to do is I want to create a log for performance purposes i.e. I want to log how long it took to read each file and how long it took to perform other non-exception related tasks.

I have tried to use the different levels of logging provided by log4net but the log.INFO etc don't accept a general message.

For example the below line of code does not work for me. Do you have a suggestion for me to be able to make this work or shall I create my own logging class for tasks like the below?

```
log.Info("Wrote file in {0}ms", elapsed2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [InfoFormat method](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.ILog.InfoFormat_overloads.html):

```
log.InfoFormat("Wrote file in {0}ms", elapsed2);
```

All of the log4net log methods (log.Debug, log.Warn, etc) come with an additional Format method that works similarly to string.Format.

Comment: Thanks for this. That's exactly the method I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at this [log4net page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html)? Here's the interface for info:

```
namespace log4net
{
    public interface ILog
    {
        /* Test if a level is enabled for logging */
        bool IsDebugEnabled { get; }
        bool IsInfoEnabled { get; }
        bool IsWarnEnabled { get; }
        bool IsErrorEnabled { get; }
        bool IsFatalEnabled { get; }

        /* Log a message object */
        void Info(object message);
        ...

        /* Log a message object and exception */
        void Info(object message, Exception t);
        ...

        /* Log a message string using the System.String.Format syntax */
        void InfoFormat(string format, params object[] args);
        ...

        /* Log a message string using the System.String.Format syntax */
        void InfoFormat(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args);
        ...
    }
}
```

Choose the one you like :)

Comment: Thanks alot for the link and the code. I didn't see that page before. Just wanna say this forum is amazing with so many great people willing to help. :)